# Iteration over inline-initialized array?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell, and have stumbled across some behavior I can't explain while trying to do something fairly straightforward.  I have a few variables containing paths within the file system, and I want to make sure that they all have trailing slashes (and add them if they're missing).

```
# append trailing slash if not present
$engineXCopyPath, $engineXBackupPath, $enlistmentBuildTargetPath | ForEach-Object
{
    Write-Host "hi" #where I would check the last character and add a \ if it weren't
}
```

When running my script, this code keeps prompting for `Process[_n_]` until I give it no input, in which case it prints the entire contents of the line rather than executing it.

As far as I know, it should be iterating over the three items fed to it, printing "hi" for each one.  I'm not sure why it's prompting for any input (not to mention why it stops when I give it blank input), nor do I know why it's printing `"Write-Host "hi" #where I would check the last character and add a \ if it weren't"` instead of just `"hi"`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the opening brace on the same line as ForEach-Object:

```
$engineXCopyPath, $engineXBackupPath, $enlistmentBuildTargetPath | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "hi" #where I would check the last character and add a \ if it weren't
}
```

Otherwise, PowerShell is prompting you for the `Process` input scriptblocks that are required for `ForEach-Object`. Then it is interpreting the braces as the creation of a ScriptBlock and printing the contents.

Comment: @Benjin - To clarify, Foreach-Object is a Cmdlet.  The script block you are passing in is just a positional parameter.  You can't continue parameters for a command on the next line.  An example using named parameters: `1,2,3 | Foreach-Object -begin {$x = 2} -Process {$x * $_}`.  Foreach () {} is a keyword.  For this, you can start the curly on the next line.

Comment: I think I get it.  So by starting the open-curly-brace on the same line, the Cmdlet knows I'm passing a parameter, and knows that parameter will continue until it hits the appropriate close-brace?

Comment: @Benjin Yes, the parser knows the input is incomplete when there is an unmatched opening brace.